# Laravel 5.3 на хосте(Centos 6.7)

Tags: angularjs, laravel, centos

Хотел поставить на хостинг, ларовел в сборке с ангуларом вот от [сюда](https://laravel-angular.readme.io/).
И столкнулся с проблемой 500 ошибки. Использовал инструкции с официального сообщества по установке ларавела на centos.
В логах выдает ошибку

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getPrefix() on null in /www/* .ru/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 49

судя по всему ошибка в роутинге с функцией getPrefix,хотя на локалке(Lamp) все работает хорошо.
файл httpd.conf

> < VirtualHost *:81 >
>           ServerName * .ru
>           CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/* .ru.access.log combined
>           DocumentRoot /www/*.ru/public
>
>           ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/* .ru.error.log
>           ServerAlias www.* .ru
>           AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
>           AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
>           DirectoryIndex index.php
>
> < Directory /www/*.ru>
>           Options -ExecCGI -Includes
>           php_admin_flag engine on
>           AllowOverride All
>   < /Directory>

Параметры хоста:
PHP 5.6.22
Centos 6.7

Файл .htaccess. Комментирование строки "Options -MultiViews" в нем, тоже не дало результата

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Чмоды 755? на папку с файлами? Что показывают логи?

Comment: @Evgeniy Я поставил 777 на /storage и /bootstrap/cache. 
На сервере, в логах, была ошибка "Call to a member function getPrefix() on null in /www/* .ru/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 49" сейчас глянул в логах ларавела
"local.ERROR: exception 'Exception' with message 'There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system' in *.ru/vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random.php:185"

Comment: @Evgeniy поставил вот чмоды 755  -р  на все папки не помогло. В логах теперь появилось "Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "*ru/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in *ru/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107"

Comment: Может, версия php старовата? Дока пишет: PHP between 5.6.4 & 7.1.*

Comment: @Confireus Я в конце концов поставил ту сборку просто на ubuntu server на heroku и все зафурычило. Но возможно ты прав, и здесь дело в версии. Сейчас проверять нет необходимости.